# How to auto start the video using exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using exo-player as a video player for my application. I am unable to start the videos automatically as it is opened in the gallery mode.
I need to click on play button to play the video.

How do I make it autoplay instead of click and play?

I used the below 2 solutions which did not give the required results,

```
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady();
```

edit -

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    Log.e("Scroll",String.valueOf(distanceY)+" - "+String.valueOf(distanceX));
    if(distanceY>-40&&distanceY<-20&&distanceX<10){
        ImageCorouselViewActivity.this.finish();

        try {
            int position = vpImageCorousel.getCurrentItem();

            if(listImagesViewPagers.get(position).isVideo()) {
                //exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                exoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
        ImageCorouselViewActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.stay,R.anim.slide_down);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you post your complete code here, where you are initializing `exoplayer`

Comment: Added @AbdulKawee

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `prepare()` on exoplayer

```
if(listImagesViewPagers.get(position).isVideo()) {
            //exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            exoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
            // Prepare the player with the source.
            mPlayer.prepare(mVideoSource);
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Source is from server. All the videos are being loaded from server. How to get the required in the above code?

Comment: yeah try to pass the video url in it

Comment: They aren't static. They are dynamic

Comment: so whats the issue in adding dynamic url? are you using `RecylerView` or some thing/

Comment: getPlaybackState returns an Int but you are not using it so whats the point of adding it here unless you do Int return = exoPlayer.getPlaybackState() and then do something with that return value.  Like using STATE_READY